# Alarm successfully sets for future time, but not for Calendar date

Tags: java, android, notifications, calendar, alarmmanager

I have this app where i want to set a notification on a specific date the user defines. I saw lots of code and relative answers here on SO but for some reason nothing works so far.

In this test project i have 2 methods. One that sets an alarm to ring 5 seconds on future and one that assigns the desired date.

**Problem:**

If i set the alarm to a second delay it works fine. The notification is shown within 5 seconds after the alarm assignment. **But** if i use the method that passes a `Calendar` date, it does nothing. Not triggers no notification

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void setAlarmOnClick(View view){
        // this method call works fine
        setAlarm(getNotification("Date test"), 3000);
        // this one doesn't
        // setAlarm(getNotification("Date test"), getDate());
    }

    // Here nothing happens when the date comes
    private void setAlarm(Notification notification, Calendar cal) {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationPublisher.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, 1);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION, notification);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent );
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm worked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    // This alarm get successfully trigger here showing the notification
    private void setAlarm(Notification notification, int delay) {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationPublisher.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, 1);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION, notification);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, delay, pendingIntent );
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm worked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private Calendar getDate(){
        Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,8);
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,2017);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,29);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,11);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,47);
        return cal;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    private Notification getNotification(String content) {
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentTitle("Scheduled Notification");
        builder.setContentText(content);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

**NotificationPublisher.java**

```
public class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification-id";
    public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm worked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
        NotificationManager notofManager = (NotificationManager)context. getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
        notofManager.notify(id, notification);

    }
}
```

I would really appreciate anykind of help!

*P.S.*

How can i be sure that an alarm was successfully set on a date. Even if a code works and a date is set a week form now. How can i test that it will trigger then? Obviously we can't wait a week to see that. Changing the device date is working? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Calendar month goes from 0-11 instead of 1-12 as u assumed.
So something like:

```
cal.set(Calendar.Month, 7 );
```

would set your calendar month to August.